# jQuery event bubbling with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, jquery

I am having a hard time getting some jQuery functions to work like it should.

I have a like button on my site that works until new items are appended, then it stop to work.
This worked when I had the following code:

```
$('.like').toggle(
    function() {
        console.log('href');
    }, function() {
        console.log('rel');
    }
);
```

A friend of mine directed me to event bubbling, but I am having a hard time getting it to work.

Here is what I have at the moment.

the simple HTML

```
​<button href='123.html' rel='456.html' class='like'>Click here</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

the jQuery, wrapped in $(document).ready( ...
I have tried the toggle function, and it seems **like** the button is asleep for the first **click**, then it suddenly wakes up and performs the event.

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.like')) {
        var $like = $(event.target);
        $like.toggle(
            function() {
                console.log('href');
            }, function() {
                console.log('rel');
            }
        );
    }
});​
```

What should the code be like in order to keep working when new items are appended and make sure that the button does not act this way

Here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/_entreprenerd/SpmbQ/

Comment: could you post a fiddle to reproduce the issue (or a simple demo page)?

Comment: @F.Calderan just added the fiddle to the description. thanks

Comment: Why you are going for event bubbling when you had no issues earlier?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal If you read the earlier bit, It worked fine until the new ajax items are appended, then the "like" button stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, we can't delegate "toggle", because toggle is not an event, it's just a method in jQuery. So you need to implement your own toggle functionality for delegated events.

Sample solution:

```
$("body").on("click", ".like", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var toggled= $this.data("toggled");
    if (toggled) {
        console.log('rel');
    } else {
        console.log('href');
    }
    $this.data("toggled", !toggled);
});
```

I'd also suggest changing the selector in the above code from "body" to parent container of .like elements, so the delegation has shorter way up the document tree.

and a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2pXr/3/

Comment: you legend! Thanks I will test this with new appended ajax items to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need delegate event handler for resolve your issue.

```
$('body').on('click', '.like', function() {
  $(this).toggle(
    function() {
        console.log('href');
    }, function() {
        console.log('rel');
    });
}).click();
```

See **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

you have also [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

```
$('body').delegate('.like', 'click', function() {
  $(this).toggle(
    function() {
        console.log('href');
    }, function() {
        console.log('rel');
    });
}).click();
```

**NOTE** Instead of body you can use **container** that holds the `.like`.

Comment: thanks for a detailed explanation, but I still find it does the same thing. see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/_entreprenerd/SpmbQ/

Comment: the like button contains a like / unlike in the href and rel, which is used to fire off a like or unlike. also I tried the jsfiddle in chrome and firefox, it still takes one click to wake up, only then does the functions start working...

Comment: The code from this anwer required that additional click, because on click event it just registers a new click event using the toggle function. The problem is that toggle is not a event, so it cannot be delegated, so you need to "simulate" toggle behavior yourself. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for jQuery versions < 1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Either the solution by thecodeparadox or
Hook the event after the ajax call has added new elements in the DOM. But thecodeparadox's solution is better.